# Using SQL charindex to get string between quotes or multiple strings between occurrence or quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

we are having to ID some data coming from a bad import and any help would be appreciated.
For instance a string like below and identifier char for the charindex.

```
SET @InputString  = 'The quick brown fox jumped "over" or "under" the log'
SET @IdentifierChar = '"'
```

The issue we are having is that we can run our test against a hard coded string like the one above and get the result of 'over'. we have tried to put it in a while loop and then we get 'over','or','under'. The Expected Result for us would be only returning 'over', 'under' and not the or.

Our first go at a test was something like below just to see try and split:

```
DECLARE @InputString Nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @IdentifierChar NCHAR(1)
SET @InputString  = 'The quick brown fox jumped "over" or "under" the log'
SET @IdentifierChar = '"'

declare @FirstID int
declare @SecondID int
declare @Length int
declare @TargetString Nvarchar(MAX)

Set @FirstID = CHARINDEX(@IdentifierChar,@InputString,1)
Set @SecondID = CHARINDEX(@IdentifierChar,@InputString,@FirstID+1)
Set @Length = @SecondID-@FirstID
Set @TargetString = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@FirstID+1,@Length-1)
```

Like I said then we literally just threw it in a hard coded loop and set the value of the substring to the last position of the identifier of the specialcharacter just to test and see how the charindex was splitting out the strings between the quotes and we did not think about it getting the 'or' as well.

so here is the dirty loop:

```
Set @COUNT = 0
Set @Length = 0
WHILE(@COUNT)<3
BEGIN
Set @FirstID = CHARINDEX(@IdentifierChar,@InputString,@Length)
Set @SecondID = CHARINDEX(@IdentifierChar,@InputString,@FirstID+1)
Set @Length = @SecondID-@FirstID
Set @TargetString = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@FirstID+1,@Length-1)
SET @COUNT = @COUNT+1
Set @Length =@SecondID
END
```

Comment: You can't expect direct answers and  the entire code from stackoverflow community. Please show the code what you have written for the specified problem and where you have gone wrong. So that solution can be found.

Comment: `mysql` or `sql-server`? Pick one.

Comment: we use sql server! Sorry I was in between meeting and thought I had added the code that we were playing with as a test. Like I said we are java guys and have no problem doing this if we could select all the data out and just write in in java but with the requirements we have been give this has to be done on the sql server so we are all trying to figure it out and find/build a example that we can then document and use and a teaching tool for ourselves as to how we solved this problem in the event it happens in the future.

Comment: Are you trying to find an arbitrary number of quoted values per string, or are you definitely just looking for two of them, no more, no less?

Comment: It will be arbitrary, not a huge number but could be more than 2

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to parse this out, but here's my minimal  modification to your code to make it work, with comments where I changed things:

```
DECLARE @InputString Nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @IdentifierChar NCHAR(1)
SET @InputString  = 'The quick brown fox jumped "over" or "under" the log'
SET @IdentifierChar = '"'

declare @FirstID int
declare @SecondID int
declare @Length int
declare @TargetString Nvarchar(MAX)

declare @COUNT int   -- added this missing from your code above
Set @COUNT = 0
Set @Length = 0
WHILE(@COUNT)<2  -- only need 2 here now
BEGIN
Set @FirstID = CHARINDEX(@IdentifierChar,@InputString,@Length)
Set @SecondID = CHARINDEX(@IdentifierChar,@InputString,@FirstID+1)
Set @Length = @SecondID-@FirstID
Set @TargetString = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@FirstID+1,@Length-1)
SET @COUNT = @COUNT+1
Set @Length =@SecondID+1    -- added one
print @TargetString         -- so we can see what it finds
END
```

Your main issue was updating @Length at the bottom of your loop -- when you thought you were pointing PAST the double quote after "over", you were actually pointing right at it and finding it a second time as an open-quote before " or ".

Comment: i posted the code. it was a hard coded loop just to run through 3x to make sure we saw the 2 occurrences. basically because it worked correctly to get the fist string in quote we were just screwing around to see if we we could run a loop based on some variable while we update a index and keep checking the remaing porting of the substring. We were shocked we got the 'or' in the test, but we guess it is technically between 2 quotes even though it is not what we are going after. This is simple in java, but sucks in sql.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot more sense. ok so getting out of this hardcoded loop, how to you make if run and only run twice due to the fact that if it runs multiple times it pulls in more results? In other languages you could just search for the number of found occurrences set that to a variable, make that  your variable against count and you are good to go, but that is not so easy here it does not seem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your data set and the complexity of your overall query, you could use a recursive CTE:

```
;with inputStr as (select 'The quick brown fox jumped "over" or "under" or "around" the log' as s)

,cte as (
select right(s,len(s) - charindex('"',s) + 1) as s  --get the first occurence of "
from inputStr
union ALL
select right(right(s,len(s)-1),len(s) - charindex('"',s) + 1) as s --get the second occurence of " in the above string
from cte
where charindex('"',s) > 0  --where " exists
)

select left(s,charindex('"',right(s,len(s)-1))+1) as quoted --select from the first " to the second "
from cte
where (len(s) - len(replace(s,'"',''))) % 2 <> 1  --even number of "
and left(s,charindex('"',right(s,len(s)-1))+1) like '"%"'
```

Comment: This does eliminate the 'or' problem, but what if there are more that just 2 valid sets of strings in quotes? How would we handle that dynamically?

Comment: @MACQUICCLEY it still works. See edits, I inserted a third string and didn't change the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a User Defined Function that I wrote and keep in my toolbox. This is a slightly off-label use, but it should work well for you.

If we consider this string to be five substrings, delimited by the four double-quote characters, then we can split on those just take substrings 2 and 4.  (Getting a third or fourth quoted value would be as easy as getting substrings 6 or 8)  Trying to get an element that doesn't exist will just return a NULL.

After executing the CREATE statement below, which will create the dbo.SPLIT_LIST function, you can call it like this:

```
declare @InputString varchar(255)
SET @InputString  = 'The quick brown fox jumped "over" or "under" the log'

select dbo.SPLIT_LIST(@InputString, '"', 2, ''),
       dbo.SPLIT_LIST(@InputString, '"', 4, '')
```

And you'll get your two output values.  What's nice about a function like this is you can just throw it in your select statements and operate over many records at a time, instead of per each.

```
CREATE function dbo.SPLIT_LIST(
  @string nvarchar(max), 
  @delimiter nvarchar(50), 
  @i int, 
  @text_qualifier nvarchar(1)
  )

returns nvarchar(max)
/*
  returns a selected element from a delimited list

  select dbo.SPLIT_LIST_w_Qualifier('"twenty,one","twenty,two","twenty,three"', ',', 2,'"')
  returns:  'twenty,two'

  Note: can ignore embedded text qualifiers
*/

as
BEGIN


declare @value nvarchar(max),
        @d_length int,
        @next_delimiter nvarchar(51),
        @q_length int, --length of the text qualifier
        @trim int,
        @using_qualifier int

set @d_length = len(@delimiter)
set @q_length = len(@text_qualifier)
set @string = ltrim(rtrim(@string))

--works by chopping off the leading value from the string each round

while @i > 0 and @string is not null and len(@string) > 0
begin

  --if the remaining @string starts with the text qualifier, 
  --then the currently parsed value should end with the text qualifier+delimiter
  if left(@string,1) = @text_qualifier 
     begin
      set @using_qualifier = 1
      --chop off leading qualifier
      set @string = ltrim(right(@string,(len(@string)-len(@text_qualifier))))
     end
    else 
     begin
      set @using_qualifier = 0
     end

  if (@using_qualifier = 0) -- If we are NOT using a text qualifier for this element
  begin
    if (charindex(@delimiter, @string) > 0) --If there is a remaining delimiter
    begin
      set @value = ltrim(rtrim(left(@string, charindex(@delimiter, @string)-1)))
      set @string = ltrim(rtrim(right(@string, len(@string)-charindex(@delimiter, @string) - @d_length + 1)))
    end
    else --no remaining delimiters
    begin
      set @value = @string
      set @string = null
    end
  end
  else -- If we ARE using a text qualifier for this element
  begin
    if (charindex((@text_qualifier+@delimiter), @string) > 0) --If there is a remaining qualifier+delimiter
    begin
      set @value = ltrim(rtrim(left(@string, charindex((@text_qualifier+@delimiter), @string)-1)))
      set @string = ltrim(rtrim(right(@string, len(@string)-charindex((@text_qualifier+@delimiter), @string) - @d_length - @q_length + 1)))
    end
    else --no remaining qualifier+delimiters
    begin
      --Does the remaining string END with the text qualifier?
      if (charindex(REVERSE(@text_qualifier), REVERSE(@string)) = 1)
      begin
        set @value = ltrim(rtrim(left(@string, len(@string)-@q_length)))
        set @string = null
      end
      else if (charindex((@text_qualifier), @string) > 0) --Is there a remaining qualifier at all?
      begin
        set @value = ltrim(rtrim(left(@string, charindex((@text_qualifier), @string)-1)))
        set @string = null
      end
      else  --no final closing qualifier
      begin
        set @value = @string
        set @string = null
      end
    end
  end

  set @i = @i - 1

  --print @value

end

if @i = 0 return @value  --should exit here

return NULL              --a parse too far exists here

END
```

Comment: Happy to help, @MACQUICCLEY - don't forget to accept an answer if you found one helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update. I continued to toy around with the code and got something to work in case anyone wants to use similar logic in the future. This did what we discussed above.

```
DECLARE @TargetString NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @stringLen int
DECLARE @splitTbl TABLE(siteId NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @idChar NCHAR(1)

SET @TargetString = 'The quick brown fox jumped "over" or "under" the "log"'
SET @stringLen = CHARINDEX(' ', @TargetString)
SET @idChar = '"'

WHILE CHARINDEX(' ', @TargetString) > 0
BEGIN
SET @stringLen = CHARINDEX(' ', @TargetString);

INSERT INTO @splitTbl
SELECT SUBSTRING(@TargetString,1,@stringLen - 1);

SET @TargetString = SUBSTRING(@TargetString, @stringLen + 1, 
LEN(@TargetString));
END

DECLARE @buildResults NVARCHAR(MAX)
INSERT INTO @splitTbl
SELECT @TargetString

DECLARE @buildLike NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @buildLike = '%'+@idChar+'%'
SELECT  @buildResults = COALESCE(@buildResults + ', ', '') 
+SUBSTRING(siteId, 2, lEN(siteId) - 2)
FROM @splitTbl
WHERE siteId LIKE @buildLike
```